# How hot is too hot for magnetic beds?

Tags: heated-bed

How hot is too hot for any given magnetic layer holding a steel bed surface?  Are certain types or grades of magnets more or less suited for this purpose?  How can I ascertain which kind I have if the manufacturer doesn't tell me?

I've heard that some magnetic beds should not be used for certain materials because those materials require a very hot bed for adhesion.  But in the modern age where resellers and even manufacturers don't usually know what they are selling, what are the rules of thumb, and where are the limits?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Depends on the magnets used

Magnets demagnetize under heat and are fully demagnetized once their [Curie temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curie_temperature) is reached. This Curie temperature depends heavily on the type of magnet, and it is not the point where they already suffer demagnetization but where they have none left. This means, that the useable temperature band is much lower - and in some cases, low temperature can negatively impact a magnet's holding force.

- Typical Magnet tapes and foils as one uses them for example kitchen magnets can start to fail as early as 65 °C and have Curie temperatures around 80-85 °C - making them unsuitable for printing high-temperature printing.
- The Chromium-Oxide magnetic tapes on cassettes are totally demagnetized at 113 °C.
- [Neodymium-iron-boron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neodymium_magnet) magnets stuffer permanent damage over 100 °C and totally lose their magnetization at the Curie temperature of 320 °C
- [Samarium–cobalt magnets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samarium%E2%80%93cobalt_magnet) only suffer damage over 250 to 550 °C and have a Curie Temperature of 700 to 850 °C,